# Removing free partition on Macbook Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, efi

Let me tell you the story to understand the problem.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my mac as the second OS. Later I decided to delete it, and being not good in all this stuff, I decided to just remove the 30gb partition I gave for Ubuntu. However, EFI partition was left.

I downloaded Paragon and erased this EFI. But it is not merged still with my Macintosh HD!

[image: Paragon - disks structure]

So my question is how to merge it (include literally the 314.57 Mb partition) with my hard disk (APFS-container)?

I tried to format it as HFS+ and then tried to make it APSF but my system felt and I had to install macOS again.

P.S. Disk Utility says that there is a trouble and to repair it, I need to go to recovery mode. But when I go to RM, it says the same thing - even though I turned off filevault as some sources say.

I will be very thankful to you for your response!

Comment: Boot to your ubuntu live-usb, and select try ubuntu. You can delete the partitions with gparted leaving only OSX related parts. When you boot back into OSX, you can extend the Macintosh HD partition.

Comment: Thank you! is that built in, or i need to get it through terminal ?

Comment: As I recall right it is downloadable with PPA and 'apt'. But that might also be present in common apt servers nowadays. Has been a while since I used ubuntu, arch guy now. When you boot search for "gparted", if it is not present a quick google can redirect you to proper ppa installation.

Comment: Still can’t do anything - there’s just an unallocated partition which can be formatted but that’s it.

Comment: You are not suppose to delete the EFI partition. You are suppose to mount the EFI partition and remove the folders `EFI/BOOT` and `EFI/ubuntu` on the FAT32 format volume stored in the EFI partition.

Comment: @BerkIlgar: There is no macOS command that can extend a partition to include free space before the partition. You can only issue macOS  command to extend certain types of partitions on GPT drives to include free space immediately after the partition.  I should also point out that `Macintosh HD` is not a partition.

Comment: Does the EFI folder come with macOS? I mean suppose I just bought a Mac from apple store, will there be EFI folder, or that folder was created by Ubuntu? Cuz now when I go to first aid, the disk utility says there is a trouble with booting

Comment: Yes, the EFI partition came with macOS. (The EFI partition contains a FAT32 formatted volume labeled EFI which contains an EFI folder.) It would be impossible for Ubuntu to have created this partition. To do so would have required Ubuntu to have moved the entire APFS partition to create the space.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! And sorry, i cannot vote - i have no reputation here

Comment: I assume you know how to put the partition back.

Comment: Reinstall macOS without erasing the disk?

Answer (score 0):

You a not suppose to remove the EFI partition. This partition was created when macOS was installed. To remove the Ubuntu files from the FA32 formatted volume stored in this partition, take the following steps.

> Note: I realize, it is to late for you to follow these steps. I post the steps for others who may have the same question.

1. Boot to macOS and open a Terminal application window.
2. Enter the command below to mount the volume stored in the EFI partition. This volume will have the name `EFI`.

   ```
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
   ```
3. Use the Finder application to remove the `EFI/BOOT` and `EFI/ubuntu` folders from the `EFI` volume.
4. Enter the command below to unmount the volume stored in the EFI partition.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```